# How to from a JSON, get a field, and send the rest of the JSON as a byte[]

Tags: c#, json, deserialization, json-deserialization

I have the following JSON

```
{   
   "Guid": "abc", 
   "Data": {
      "Json": [[1,42],[2,2]]
 }
```

And I would like to get it into this:

```
public class TempData
{
    public string Guid { get; set; }
    public Json Data { get; set; }
}

public class Json
{
    public byte[] Data { get; set; }
}
```

Using the following code i get the byte[] Data null, can anyone tell me why?

```
TempData data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TempData>(jsonString);
```

Best regards

Comment: What would the `byte[]` contain? Your source data is a string, not bytes, and the JSON doesn't even represent a list of integers.

Comment: It would contain a Json, it could have anything, that was just an example.
`
{
  "Guid": "abc",
  "Data": {
    "Json": [
      {
        "source": "asd",
        "target": "asd"
      }
    ]
  }
}
`

Answer (score 0):

You have two mistakes in the mapping between your JSON and your serialized class:

The JSON contains a property `Data`, which is an object with property `Json` whereas the class contains a property `Data` which has a property `Data`. To fix this, modify the class as follows:

```
public class TempData
{
    public string Guid { get; set; }
    public DataData { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public byte[] Json { get; set; }
}
```

The Json-property in the Json-document contains an array of arrays of ints. This cannot be serialized to a byte array. There are two possible options:

Change the Json to contain a proper byte array:

```
{   
   "Guid": "abc", 
   "Data": {
      "Json": [1,42,2,2]
 }
```

Or modify your class so it has an array of byte arrays:

```
public class TempData
{
    public string Guid { get; set; }
    public DataData { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public byte[][] Json { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I solved it by sendind the data into a object. Now I need to figure out a way to convert it to byte[], since the JObject of the JSON.net isn't "tagged" with the  Serializable atribute.